# Проблема во время билда апк для релиза, когда происходит билд для дебага — все ок, что делать?

Tags: android, android-studio

во время билда апк для релиза(Generate Signed APK...) происходит ошибка

> :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease FAILED Error:Execution
> failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:

(Так же хочу заметить, что во время билда для дебага все ок и никаких ошибок не происходит)

**Вот лог действий:**

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2411Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesContextmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareSubwayKiev132CheetahMobile347UnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareSubwayKiev132UnityAds158UnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:prePackageMarkerForRelease
<b>:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/unity3d/ads/android/BuildConfig.class
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 6.273 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**Вот мой build,gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.subwaykiev10"
        minSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile project(':unity-ads-1.5.8')
    compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')
    //compile(project(':..:..:..:..:..:..:android_libraries:walletsdkandroidmodule')) {
    //    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
    //}

}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

**build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Ну и что у меня за файлы вообще в проекте**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
duplicate entry: com/unity3d/ads/android/BuildConfig.class
```

Это значит, что у вас подключено 2 библиотеки unity-ads. Вы подключили два jar с разными версиями этой библиотеки. Проверьте и удалите одну из них. Скорее всего, одна подключена через отдельный проект (compile project(':unity-ads-1.5.8')), а вторая лежит в libs.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего подключённые модули используют одинаковые библиотеки.

Проверить это не сложно, простой способ:

переходите на вкладку **Project** -> **External Libraries**
и там анализируете и сравниваете используемые библиотеки.

Затем в build.gradle одну из конфликтующих библиотек включаете в `exclude` соответствующего модуля

Comment: Я скоро опробую ваш вариант решения и отпишу(жду пока скинут проект)

Comment: Повторяющихся библиотек нету, есть, конечно типа
firebase-analytics-9.4.0 и firebase-analytics-impl-9.4.0
Но это ведь разные библиотеки?

Comment: там могут быть классы с одинаковой сигнатурой - имя пакета и имя класса полностью совпадают

Comment: А точнее можно, что конкретно искать?

Comment: @Bellkross указал на один из проектов unity-ads-1.5.8 ищите класс com.unity3d.ads.android.BuildConfig там и в одной из jar-ок. Это не обязательно разные версии библиотек.